# Altering the data format in the list

Tags: python, list, combinations

I need a little change in the following code.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations, product
from pprint import pprint


data = {
        'uc':(1, 'ABCDEF'),  
        'lc':(2, 'abcdef'),  
        'no':(3, '123456'), 
        }

def main():
    iters = [combinations(l,n) for n,l in data.values()]
    combine_list = []
    for count, group in data.values():
        print('picking {} of {}'.format(count, group))

        combine_list.append(list(combinations(group, count)))


    combos = list(product(*combine_list))
    pprint(combos)

main()
```

Instead of the given sets 'ABCDEF', 'abcdef' and '123456', I want to enter the values in this format:

```
data = {
        'uc':(1, '(A,B,C),(D,E),F'),  
        'lc':(2, '(a,b,c),(d,e),f'), 
        'no':(3, '(1,2,3),(4,5),6'), 
        }
```

and in this case, the code would treat the values between () as a single item. I tried this but it doesn't give the result I want when I do that. How should I do it so it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you have one string as your overall sequence:

```
'(A,B,C),(D,E),F'
```

Maybe you want a list of elements, like:

```
# the string '(A,B,C)' is a single element here
['(A,B,C)', '(D,E)', 'F']
```

or

```
# the tuple of strings ('A','B','C') is a single element here
[('A','B','C'),('D','E'),'F']
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to access the dict and loop over the items and rearrange them in a format you like:

```
data = {
        'uc':(1, 'ABCDEF'),  
        'lc':(2, 'abcdef'),  
        'no':(3, '123456'), 
        }

for k,v in data.items():
    num = v[0]
    strings = [i for i in v[1]]
    first = ','.join(i for i in strings[:3])
    second = ','.join(i for i in strings[3:5])
    third = strings[5]
    data[k] = (v[0],'({}),({}),{}'.format(first,second,third))

>> {'uc': (1, '(A,B,C),(D,E),F'),
 'lc': (2, '(a,b,c),(d,e),f'),
 'no': (3, '(1,2,3),(4,5),6')}
```